# No output with template-string

Tags: javascript, express, template-strings

I try to use the npm qrcode API with express. When the user enters an address into a form, the QR-Code should be displayed on the website. I searched for a long time, but can't figure it out, since I don't understand what to loog for exactly.

I tried the following:

```js
app.post('/ausgabe', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.setHeader('200', { 'Content-type': 'application/json' });
    const eingabe = `'${req.body.address}'`;

    const qrImage = await generateQR(eingabe);
    console.log(qrImage);

    const body = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>QR-Code</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img ${qrImage} />
    </body>
    </html>`;
    res.send(body);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({
      status: 'Fail',
      message: err,
    });
  }
});
```

I console.logged 'qrImage' and it's there and correct, but there is nothing showing up in the HTML.

Thanks a lot,
TobiG

Comment: You are including whatever the string output of qr image is, can you show what console log qrImage gives you?

Comment: The snippet editor has four parts. Each has a specific job. Why did you paste your _script_ in the _HTML_ section?

Comment: I think the content-type is wrong. It should be `content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Do you need to put it into a `src` attribute in the image? `<img src="${qrImage}" />`

Comment: @TJBlackman Thanks, that was the solution. The qrcode API gave me some code that didn't include the 'src=' .
Also there was a mistake at
const eingabe = `'${req.body.address}'`;  --> the single quotes weren't necessary. 
Thanks for your help.